# How can I change the font size of locally installed KDE application menus and dialogs?

Tags: kde, fonts, home-directory

I use GNOME 3.14.1. I have a KDE application (KDEnlive) compiled and installed in home folder (not system-wide).

How can I change font size and font for applications like this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. The config file in my case is located in `/home/r/kdenlive/20150506/.kde/share/config` . It's `kdeglobals` file. The example of this file in my case:

```
[$Version]
update_info=kded.upd:kde3.0,kdeui.upd:kde4/migrate_from_kde3_icon_theme

[KFileDialog Settings]
Automatically select filename extension=true
Breadcrumb Navigation=true
Decoration position=0
LocationCombo Completionmode=5
PathCombo Completionmode=5
Previews=false
Show Bookmarks=false
Show Full Path=false
Show Preview=false
Show Speedbar=true
Show hidden files=true
Sort by=Name
Sort directories first=true
Sort reversed=false
Speedbar Width=135
View Style=Simple
listViewIconSize=0

[General]
desktopFont=Ubuntu,11,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
fixed=Ubuntu Mono,14,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
font=Ubuntu,11,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
menuFont=Ubuntu,11,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
smallestReadableFont=Ubuntu,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
taskbarFont=Ubuntu,11,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
toolBarFont=Ubuntu,11,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0
widgetStyle=gtk+
```

I used *systemsetting* application(installed from repository) and then copied the part(which concerned to fonts) of created by this application file `/home/'user'/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals` to this file(which belongs to installed into home directory configuration of kdenlive and kde) `/home/'user'/kdenlive/20150506/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals`.